# Fill area to match the lines of with various 'type' arguments in lattice

Tags: r, plot, panel, area, lattice

I know I can use `panel.xyarea` from latticeExtra to fill the area in the plot with any colour. Without defining a `type` argument in `xyplot`, such filling will follow the route of default `type="p"`:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
data <- data.frame(time=1:24,value=rnorm(24))
xyplot(value~time, data, 
       panel=function(x,y,...){
             panel.xyarea(x,y,...)
             panel.xyplot(x,y,...)})
```

[image]

This plots both `panel.xyarea` and the points coming from default `type="p"` in `panel.xyplot`. Now the problem arise when I want to change the `type` of plotting line, for example making it step function `type="S"`:

```
xyplot(value~time, data, type="S",
       panel=function(x,y,...){
             panel.xyarea(x,y,...)
             panel.xyplot(x,y,...)}
```

[image]

As you see on the example above, `panel.xyarea` doesn't fill the area underneath the new step function, but instead it plots both areas overlapping. It doesn't change anything if I move `type="S"` to the `panel.xyarea` - in fact it doesn't register `type` argument it at all and plots as it wouldn't be there.

Is there a way I can bypass this and have `panel.xyarea` fill my plots whatever type I define - be it step function (`type="S"`), loess (`type="smooth"`) or regression (`type="r"`)? Or maybe there is something better than `panel.xyarea` to use in such context?

Comment: No, there's no simple and fully general way to do this (without modifying a number of different **lattice** functions). Are you interested in not completely general (but simple) solutions for particular values of `type=`?

Comment: Sure, lets start somewhere, shoot @Josh

Comment: OK, I'll put together a couple of quick examples, for `type="S"` and `type="smooth"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each value of `type`, you'll need to construct a custom panel function. Fortunately, if you model the functions closely on existing **lattice** code (starting out by having a look at `panel.xyplot`), that shouldn't be too hard. For example, the two custom panel functions below include many lines of code but only a couple of lines (marked with comments) that I had to write.

Once you've defined the panel functions (copying them in from the code blocks following the figure), use them like this:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
library(gridExtra)
set.seed(100)
data <- data.frame(time=1:24,value=rnorm(24))

## Filled version of xyplot(..., type="S")
a <- xyplot(value~time, data, panel=panel.filled_S) 
## Filled version of xyplot(..., type="smooth") 
b <- xyplot(value~time, data, panel=panel.filled_smooth) 
grid.arrange(a, b, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

For a filled version of `type="S"`:

```
## Modeled on code in panel.xyplot, which is called when type=S"
panel.filled_S <-
function(x,y, ...) {
    horizontal <- FALSE                  ## Edited (may not want to hardcode)
    ord <- if (horizontal)
        sort.list(y)
    else sort.list(x)
    n <- length(x)
    xx <- numeric(2 * n - 1)
    yy <- numeric(2 * n - 1)
    xx[2 * 1:n - 1] <- x[ord]
    yy[2 * 1:n - 1] <- y[ord]
    xx[2 * 1:(n - 1)] <- x[ord][-n]
    yy[2 * 1:(n - 1)] <- y[ord][-1]
    panel.xyarea(x = xx, y = yy, ...)    ## Edited
    panel.lines(x = xx, y = yy, ...)     ## Edited
}
xyplot(value~time, data, panel=panel.filled_S, type="o")
```

For a filled version of `type="smooth"`:

```
## Modeled on code in panel.loess, called by panel.xyplot when type="smooth"
panel.filled_smooth <-
function (x, y, span = 2/3, degree = 1, family = c("symmetric",
    "gaussian"), evaluation = 50, lwd = plot.line$lwd, lty = plot.line$lty,
    col, col.line = plot.line$col, type, horizontal = FALSE,
    ..., identifier = "loess")
{
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    y <- as.numeric(y)
    ok <- is.finite(x) & is.finite(y)
    if (sum(ok) < 1)
        return()
    if (!missing(col)) {
        if (missing(col.line))
            col.line <- col
    }
    plot.line <- trellis.par.get("plot.line")
    if (horizontal) {
        smooth <- loess.smooth(y[ok], x[ok], span = span, family = family,
            degree = degree, evaluation = evaluation)
        panel.lines(x = smooth$y, y = smooth$x, col = col.line,
            lty = lty, lwd = lwd, ..., identifier = identifier)
        panel.xyarea(smooth$y, smooth$x, ...)  ## Edited
    }
    else {
        smooth <- loess.smooth(x[ok], y[ok], span = span, family = family,
            degree = degree, evaluation = evaluation)
        panel.lines(x = smooth$x, y = smooth$y, col = col.line,
            lty = lty, lwd = lwd, ..., identifier = identifier)
        panel.xyarea(smooth$x, smooth$y, ...)  ## Edited
    }
    smooth
}
```

Comment: Not sure why @Josh but the `panel.filled_S` function doesn't work when I run it on my machine - it doesn't plot a `type="S"` but the usual `type="p"`.

Comment: @GeekOnAcid Guess I copied over the wrong code. I recopied into the post just now, and it works for me. How about for you?

Comment: Yes, works fine now. You've pretty much dissected those functions to get it working, but it achieves the goal :)

Comment: Yeah, in reality, for a **one-off**, I'd just do `trace(panel.xyplot, edit=TRUE)` and insert a single line like `panel.xyarea(xx, yy, ...)` directly into the relevant function. Any modifications more complicated than that are only needed b/c, when we define a new panel function, we've taken the code chunk out of its environment of variables supplied by the rest of `panel.xyplot()`. For more **regular use**, I'd probably modify `panel.xyplot()` and related functions, naming them `panel.xyplot2()` et. al., and bundling them up in their own package that imports **lattice** and **latticeExtra**.